# Suggestion on algorithm to distribute objects of different value

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem:

Given N objects (N < 30) of different values multiple of a "k" constant i.e. k, 2k, 3k, 4k, 6k, 8k, 12k, 16k, 24k and 32k, I need an algorithm that will distribute all items to M players (M <= 6) in such a way that the total value of the objects each player gets is as even as possible (in other words, I want to distribute all objects to all players in the fairest way possible).

EDIT: By fairest distribution I mean that the difference between the value of the objects any two players get is minimal. 
Another similar case would be: I have N coins of different values and I need to divide them equally among M players; sometimes they don't divide exactly and I need to find the next best case of distribution (where no player is angry because another one got too much money).

I don't need (pseudo)code to solve this (also, this is not a homework :) ), but I'll appreciate any ideas or links to algorithms that could solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Define fairest. Does that mean that the average of what each player gets is the minimal possible distance from the max a player got and min a player got?

Comment: I added what I mean by fair (I guess it's what anybody would understand by fair distribution when it's about money :D)

Comment: It's simple to a human, but to define it mathematically is a bit tricky, so we need a consistent definition.

Comment: Are these two distributions equally fair? [1],[2,3],[4,5],[20]  and  [1],[2,5],[4,3],[20]  (Notice that the difference between min and max are the same).

Comment: I would suggest defining unfairness as the sum of squares: `uf = sum[(avg-p_i)**2 for all p]`. This is a common statistical formula. If you minimize `uf` you will get numbers which are as close to each other and the average as possible.

Comment: In the example you gave, the cooeficients you selected preeceding the "k" constant seem to be somewhat regular in nature. Do you have any information or restrictions regarding those cooeficient values preceeding k? (Must they be integers? Must they be somewhat evenly dispersed? Must they fall within a certain range?) This may simplify the algorithm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is strongly NP-complete. This means there is no way to ensure a correct solution in reasonable time. (See [3-partition-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), thanks Paul).

Instead you'll wanna go for a good approximate solution generator. These can often get very close to the optimal answer in very short time. I can recommend the [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) technique, which you will also be able to use for a ton of other NP-complete problems.

The idea is this:

1. Distribute the items randomly.
2. Continually make random swaps between two random players, as long as it makes the system more fair, or only a little less fair (see the wiki for details).
3. Stop when you have something fair enough, or you have run out of time.

This solution is much stronger than the 'greedy' algorithms many suggest. The greedy algorithm is the one where you continuously add the largest item to the 'poorest' player. An example of a testcase where greedy fails is `[10,9,8,7,7,5,5]`.

---

I did an implementation of SA for you. It follows the wiki article strictly, for educational purposes. If you optimize it, I would say a 100x improvement wouldn't be unrealistic.

```python
from __future__ import division
import random, math

values = [10,9,8,7,7,5,5]
M = 3
kmax = 1000
emax = 0

def s0():
    s = [[] for i in xrange(M)]
    for v in values:
        random.choice(s).append(v)
    return s

def E(s):
    avg = sum(values)/M
    return sum(abs(avg-sum(p))**2 for p in s)

def neighbour(s):
    snew = [p[:] for p in s]
    while True:
        p1, p2 = random.sample(xrange(M),2)
        if s[p1]: break
    item = random.randrange(len(s[p1]))
    snew[p2].append(snew[p1].pop(item))
    return snew

def P(e, enew, T):
    if enew < e: return 1
    return math.exp((e - enew) / T)

def temp(r):
    return (1-r)*100

s = s0()
e = E(s)
sbest = s
ebest = e
k = 0
while k < kmax and e > emax:
    snew = neighbour(s)
    enew = E(snew)
    if enew < ebest:
        sbest = snew; ebest = enew
    if P(e, enew, temp(k/kmax)) > random.random():
        s = snew; e = enew
    k += 1

print sbest
```

**Update:** After playing around with Branch'n'Bound, I now believe this method to be superior, as it gives perfect results for the N=30, M=6 case within a second. However I guess you could play around with the simulated annealing approach just as much.

Comment: The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem linked from the Subset Sum Wikipedia article seems like an exact analog for what he's trying to do. I like your approach.

Comment: +1. I will delete my answer as it is a subset of what you say.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna give this a shot to see how well it performs. Otherwise I can always do greedy since there's no other way of doing this in reasonable time.

Thanks to all that answered!

Comment: I would say this is NOT the 3 partition problem, because there is no requirement here that each player get the same number of items, just that the combined values be as close as possible.

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't think it is claimed that the problems are _exactly_ the same. For instance, the claim is false if M=4. It only shows that this problem is strongly NP-Complete due to a _reduction from_ 3-partition for the case M=3. In fact, it is enough to consider Subset Sum to prove that it is NP-Complete (what I had in my answer) for M=2, but the fact that it is strongly NP-Complete (for M=3) is good to know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, definitely warrants my upvote then :)

Comment: @Unknown: If you choose to use it in production, remember to optimize, so E() rus in O(1) rather than O(n). If you dislike randomised algorithms you may be able to optimize a branch'n'bound sufficiently as well.

Answer (score 2):

The greedy solution suggested by a few people seems like the best option, I ran it a bunch of times with some random values, and it seems to get it right every time.
If it's not optimal, it's at the very least very close, and it runs in O(nm) or so (I can't be bothered to do the math right now)
C# Implementation:

> ```
> static List<List<int>> Dist(int n, IList<int> values)
> {
>     var result = new List<List<int>>();
>     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
>         result.Add(new List<int>());
>     var sortedValues = values.OrderByDescending(val => val);
>     foreach (int val in sortedValues)
>     {
>         var lowest = result.OrderBy(a => a.Sum()).First();
>         lowest.Add(val);
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Comment: I like it how this and the python solution are roughly the same length.

Comment: I think that the greedy solution is nearly optimal because of the low number of bits used for the values. Basically, you can ignore the k and then the numbers are represented by 5 bits. For the 2 partition problem, a ratio of the number of bits to the number of items to partition needs to be below .96 is all. In our problem we have a ratio of 5/30 = .1666666667. However, we have a higher number of partitions so the critical ratio would be different, but I have a feeling that with such a low ratio we get good results for the greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

order the k values.
order the players.

loop over the k values giving the next one to the next player.
when you get to the end of the players, turn around and continue giving the k values to the players in the opposite direction.

Comment: This is a good start, but needs some modifications. For example, consider the following case: 3 players, with the values being 10,4,3,1,1,1. Your algorithms will result in 11,5,4, when 10,5,5 is obviously more balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly give the available object with the largest value to the player who has the least total value of objects assigned to him.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but since I'm sooo rusty at math and algorithmics, I don't know if giving the items like this will result in the best possible distribution..
This seems pretty similar to what Randy/Rubys are suggesting too..

Comment: The article @Paul refers to: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem suggests that in case of M=2 and randomly distributed object values, the difference will be up to 1/3 of the sum. (largest one will be max 4/3 of 1/2 of the sum)

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight-forward implementation of Justin Peel's answer:

```
M = 3
players = [[] for i in xrange(M)]

values = [10,4,3,1,1,1]
values.sort()
values.reverse()
for v in values:
    lowest=sorted(players, key=lambda x: sum(x))[0]
    lowest.append(v)

print players
print [sum(p) for p in players]
```

I am a beginner with Python, but it seems to work okay. This example will print

```
[[10], [4, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
[10, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Try this one: 10,9,8,7,6,6,6,5

Answer (score 0):

30 ^ 6 isn't that large (it's less than 1 billion). Go through every possible allocation, and pick the one that's the fairest by whatever measure you define.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, bruteforcing is not fast enough since I need my answer in a matter of seconds..

Comment: Since the values are fixed, you have to bruteforce it only once!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I could do this only once... I have objects of values k,2k, 3k, 4k, 6k, etc., but not the same combination of them every time!  For example, once I could try to distribute 16k, 2k, 4k, k, k, k, 2k   and another time 3k, 3k, 8k, k.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The purpose was to use the greedy solution with small improvement in the implementation, which is maybe transparent in C#:

```
static List<List<int>> Dist(int n, IList<int> values) 
{ 
    var result = new List<List<int>>(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        result.Add(new List<int>()); 
    var sortedValues = values.OrderByDescending(val => val);//Assume the most efficient sorting algorithm - O(N log(N))
    foreach (int val in sortedValues) 
    { 
        var lowest = result.OrderBy(a => a.Sum()).First();//This can be done in O(M * log(n)) [M - size of sortedValues, n - size of result]
        lowest.Add(val); 
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

Regarding this stage:

```
var lowest = result.OrderBy(a => a.Sum()).First();//This can be done in O(M * log(n)) [M - size of sortedValues, n - size of result]
```

The idea is that the list is always sorted (In this code it is done by OrderBy). Eventually, this sorting wont take more than O (log(n)) - because we just need to INSERT at most one item into a sorted list - that should take the same as a binary search.
Because we need to repeat this phase for sortedValues.Length times, the whole algorithm runs in O(M * log(n)).

So, in words, it can be rephrased as:
Repeat the steps below till you finish the `Values` values:
1. Add the biggest value to the smallest player
2. Check if this player still has the smallest sum
3. If yes, go to step 1.
4. Insert the last-that-was-got player to the sorted players list

Step 4 is the O (log(n)) step - as the list is always sorted.

Comment: You should write a little about how your ode works. It will make it much easier for people to get your idea.

Comment: Also, consider if your solution solves all cases or otherwise witch ones. As an example, you might want to consider `[6,5,4,3,3,3,3]` for M=3.

Comment: You are right. I hope that now it is explained better. Thanks!