# How to create an algorithm to distribute values of money between n people in a fair way?

Tags: algorithm

I need to create an algorithm to distribute money of different values between a fixed number of people. The ammounts of money cannot be splitted.

Example: I have four ammounts of money: US$10, US$20, US$50 and US$90. What is the best way to distribute this money between two friends in such a way that they have an fair value? It is: the difference between the values is the least possible.

For this case the best solution would be:
Friend #1: US$10, US$20 and US$50 (total = US$80).
Friend #2: US$90.

How could I begin?

Notes: all ammounts of money must be distributed. The number of persons may vary.

I need to implement it in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggestion on algorithm to distribute objects of different value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938917/suggestion-on-algorithm-to-distribute-objects-of-different-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can do brute-force for O(k^n) or dp for O(k^{2}*MAXSUM^{k — 1}).
I dont think it's possible to solve it faster. ( n is number of coins and k is number of persons).

Comment: That is true if you need an exact solution.  But greedy works really well in practice.

Comment: The greedy solution may work in some cases, but it's not always correct, it depend on the user.